# How to setup my new vps quickly?

Tags: chef-infra, puppet, vps, salt-stack

Recently I knew some words `puppet` `chef` `salt`. It seems that they are used to setup env for thousands of machines with a `master machine`.

But I just have one or two vps. How can I create a production env quick with these tools? I found some docs from `salt` but most of its docs talk about how to use master to create a new production server.

So is there some good way to create a product env for only vps.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on your question? Both puppet and chef are great configuration management tools. If you can explain in a little more detail what you are trying to achieve then maybe it will be easier to give you an educated answer.

Comment: @PeteyT I tried chef-solo, it is what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chef`, `puppet` etc. work exactly the same way irrespective of the number of VPS you want to manage. You basically write your server configuration in the form of code (in other words, template of a server). Then you run that code as many times as you like.

`chef` comes with a simpler version called `chef-solo`. If you have only 2 VPSs to manage, you will be happy with `chef-solo`, as the learning curve is much smaller.

[Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com) can be a great tool to learn `chef-solo` or `puppet`